# Is there a possibility to define dtype only once for all columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arcpy

If all the columns of the same type (eg. Float), there is a possibility that `dtype` defined only once, for all columns?

Example:

```
inarray = numpy.array([(1.54, 1111.01, 45.12,... n), 
                       (2.34, 2222.22, 11.23,... n), 
                        (5.34, 18.22, 11.11,...n)],
                  numpy.dtype([('column_name','<f8')])
```

We also want to know if it is possible to automatically generate column names?

```
numpy.dtype([('????','<f8')])
```

Comment: Does your example work?  It looks like you are defining one field, but want to fill it with `n` values.  Or do you want `n` fields?  Or a `(3,n)` 2d array without named fields?

Comment: Something like count colum ... Based on the number of columns to create a list for `dtype`? name is automatically generated when you leave empty quotation marks ... For example, count the four columns ... that is based on this number creates a list of `[('', '<f8'), ('', '<f8'), ('', '<f8'), ('', '<f8')]`? Then... `numpy.dtype(list)` ?

Comment: Does not work. This is just an example of what I want...I would like to define DTYPE for an undefined number of columns. Code is based on tables that do not always have the same number of columns

Comment: Define unique `dtype` for `n` fields...

Comment: Why a simple 2D matrix does not work for you? If you don't know the number of colums, but is he same for all the rows in a given matrix, given then a name does not 'make sense'. Just creating a 2D '<f8' should do the job.

Comment: number of columns and rows must remain the same as in the input table ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example generates 4 fields by creating the string: `'<f8,<f8,<f8,<f8'`:

```
In [126]: np.zeros((3,),np.dtype(','.join(['<f8']*4)))
Out[126]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
```

There's probably a way of constructing it with lists and tuples, but this string version is simple to understand and construct.

Some alternatives:

```
np.dtype([('field_%d'%i, '<f8') for i in range(4)])

np.dtype({'formats':['f8']*4, 'names':['f%s'%i for i in range(4)]})

np.format_parser(['f8']*4,[],[]).dtype  # auto generate names
```

Comment: I'm making a code that loads the table, converts them into an array ... do the calculations ... then the output array (with an unknown number of columns) should be converted to .gdb table...

Comment: Do you need named columns?  Why not a 2d array?  What's the source data look like?  A csv table that can be loaded with `np.genfromtxt`?

Comment: number of columns and rows must remain the same as in the input table ... Info Table from .gdb ArcGIS

Comment: OK.. `numpy.dtype([('field_%d'%i, '<f8') for i in range(COLUMNS_COUNT)])`

Answer (score 1):

Im solved problem...

```
input_array = [(1.1, 11.2, 1111.0, ...n), 
               (1.3, 2.4, 2222.22, ...n)]

columns_count = len(input_array[0])


lists = [('','<f8')] * columns_count


inarray = numpy.array(input_array,
                      numpy.dtype(lists))
```